# No module named 'langgraph.prebuilt', 'langgraph' is not a package

Tags: python, openai-api, langchain

I am trying to work with [**langgraph**](https://python.langchain.com/docs/langgraph). Although I installed all required packages, I still encounter error.

```py
from langchain_community.tools.tavily_search import TavilySearchResults
from langgraph.prebuilt import ToolExecutor

OPENAI_API_KEY = ...
TAVILY_API_KEY = ...

tools = [TavilySearchResults(max_results=1)]
tool_executor = ToolExecutor (tools)
```

The error is:

```
Exception has occurred: ModuleNotFoundError
No module named 'langgraph.prebuilt'; 'langgraph' is not a package
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'langgraph' has no attribute '__path__' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

I installed langgraph and updated `PATH`.

Comment: Using the command `pip show langgraph`, you could verify the installation. If you don't see any output from this, try this one: `pip install langchain-langgraph`